# Converting "=?UTF 8?.." (RFC 2047) to a regular string in golang

Tags: string, encoding, utf-8, go

I'm using an API and it's returning something like this for other language text:

`=?UTF 8?B?2KfZhNiu2LfZiNin2Kog2KfZhNiq2Yog2KrYrNmF2Lkg2KjZitmG?= =?UTF 8?B?INit2YHYuCDYp9mE2YLYsdin2ZPZhiDYp9mE2YPYsdmK2YUg2YjZgQ==?= =?UTF 8?B?2YfZhdmHINmF2YXYpyDYp9mU2YXZhNin2Ycg2KfZhNi52YTYp9mF?= =?UTF 8?B?2Kkg2LnYqNivINin2YTZhNmHINin2YTYutiv2YrYp9mGLnBkZg==?=`

Is this a common format? How would I go about converting this to a regular string in golang?

Golang usually handles multiple languages well, but I'm not sure about how to go about converting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aparrently your API is returning data encoded in [RFC 2047 format](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt). Basically, this defines the following:

```
encoded-word = "=?" charset "?" encoding "?" encoded-text "?="
```

Which means your charset is UTF-8 (very handy, since this is Go's native character set), and your encoding is Base64. The text you have to decode is the one between the "B?" and the "?=". So all you have to do is take that text and call:

```
base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(text)
```

to get the original UTF-8 string.

There is a [`decodeRFC2047Word()`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/39eda0dac12a53f7f0c3189e5929d171e8e0b844/src/net/mail/message.go#L681) function in the `net/mail` package of the Go stdlib, supporting encodings `B` and `Q` and charsets `UTF-8`, `US-ASCII` and `ISO-8859-1`. Unfortunately it's not exported, but you're free to take as much inspiration from it as you need ;)

**BTW:** I just noticed the charset in your example strings is `UTF 8`, which is a bit odd, since the official name of the encoding is `UTF-8`.

Comment: It has the dash, it was removed in one of my processing steps.

Answer (score 9):

Since Go 1.5 you can use [mime.WordDecoder.DecodeHeader](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/#WordDecoder.DecodeHeader):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "mime"
)

func main() {
    dec := new(mime.WordDecoder)
    header, err := dec.DecodeHeader("=?UTF-8?B?2KfZhNiu2LfZiNin2Kog2KfZhNiq2Yog2KrYrNmF2Lkg2KjZitmG?= =?UTF-8?B?INit2YHYuCDYp9mE2YLYsdin2ZPZhiDYp9mE2YPYsdmK2YUg2YjZgQ==?= =?UTF-8?B?2YfZhdmHINmF2YXYpyDYp9mU2YXZhNin2Ycg2KfZhNi52YTYp9mF?= =?UTF-8?B?2Kkg2LnYqNivINin2YTZhNmHINin2YTYutiv2YrYp9mGLnBkZg==?=")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(header)
    // Output: لخطوات التي تجمع بين حفظ القرآن الكريم وفهمه مما أملاه العلامة عبد الله الغديان.pdf
}
```

If you are using an older version of Go, you can use my replacement library: https://github.com/alexcesaro/quotedprintable